# Windows script to toggle automatic configuration script checkbox without removing any existing string value

Tags: windows, script, batch-file, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to create a bat file to toggle the automatic configuration script checkbox in Internet Explorer (see red box in screenshot)...but without removing any existing value in the related textbox (see green box in screenshot).
[image]

I checked here: [Batch file script for Enable & disable the "use automatic Configuration Script"](https://superuser.com/questions/488382/batch-file-script-for-enable-disable-the-use-automatic-configuration-script)

But that script a) removes existing values and b) seems to only disable he checkbox and never enable it.

```
@echo OFF

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set VALUE_NAME=AutoConfigURL

FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B    
    set ValueValue=%%C
)

@echo Value Name = %ValueName%
@echo Value Type = %ValueType%
@echo Value Value = %ValueValue%

IF  NOT "%ValueValue%"=="yyyy" (
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "yyyy" /f
echo Proxy Enabled
) else (
echo  Hai
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoConfigURL /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
echo Proxy Disabled
)

pause
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but it was not so easy for me to find a solution so I want to share what I found with you just in case you land in this page.

In the RegKey `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections` the 9th value of `DefaultConnectionSettings` store the flag of:

- Automatically detect settings
- Use Automatic Configuration script

Available values:
01 - neither of those 2 auto config boxes are checked
05 - just the Use automatic configuration script is checked
09 - just the Automatically detect settings is checked
0d - both of them are checked

Personally I exported the current key, I created a copy and modified it with the text editor.

Then on needs I load through Command Line the initial RegKey or the modified one through command `reg import KeyIWantToUse.reg`

Thanks to Jamie [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.scripting.vbscript/EGdKXiEcwG4) And to [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194711/leo) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674119/what-key-in-windows-registry-disables-ie-connection-parameter-automatically-det)
that helped me a lot.

Comment: The value is hanged, but it does not affect the checked box (does not uncheck it)... Win10

Answer (score 0):

Your script works, but based on faulty premise on the registry value `AutoConfigURL`. In a matter of fact, connection settings are scrambled in binary values `DefaultConnectionSettings` and `SavedLegacySettings` under `HKCU\...\Internet Settings\Connections` registry branch.
Here are encoded all “*Automatically Detect settings*” on/off, “*Use Automatic configuration script*” on/off, “*Automatic configuration script*”, “*Bypass Proxy for local servers*” on/off, Proxy details etc.

You could spend years with researching of those values structure.

Good news: by deleting values `DefaultConnectionSettings` and `SavedLegacySettings` from the registry you can set *Internet settings connections* to its primeval default condition...
For other settings: adjust it by `inetcpl.cpl` and export it to a `.reg` file for later importing.